# animate div from relative position to fixed using jquery / css on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to get a div to animate between relative position to a fixed position on scroll, so when you scroll down, you see the div slide from it's relative position, over to the right (fixed position) so it can now follow you down the page.

I'm using waypoints for the scroll function, and using jquery to add a class, then I'm trying to use css animation to get it to work. So far, it does a fade of the background colour then it just jumps to the right. I was hoping to get it to slide across.. Any ideas / help would be amazing.

Here's my code:

Waypoints / jquery:

```
$('.course-list').waypoint(function(direction){
        if(direction === 'down'){
            $('.course-list').addClass('side-bar');
        } else {
            $('.course-list').removeClass('side-bar');
        }
    },{offset:'66px'});
```

Note: I've also tried adding duration to add/removeClass, didn't work for me.

CSS:

```
section.content .introduction ul.course-list{position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;-webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;-moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;-o-transition: all 1.5s ease;transition: all 1.5s ease}

section.content .introduction ul.course-list.side-bar{-webkit-animation:slideRight 1.5s forwards;-moz-animation:slideRight 1.5s forwards;-o-animation:slideRight 1.5s forwards;animation:slideRight 1.5s forwards}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight{
    to{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;background:#ff9}
}
@-moz-keyframes slideRight{
    to{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;background:#ff9}
}
@-o-keyframes slideRight{
    to{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;background:#ff9}
}
@keyframes slideRight{
    to{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;background:#ff9}
}
```

Note: I've also tried setting to absolute positioning, it still doesn't work for me..

HTML:

```
<ul class="course-list">
    <li>Testing only</li>
    <li>Testing only</li>
    <li>Testing only</li>
    <li>Testing only</li>
    <li>Testing only</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gpv38jsv/

(it's set to do it straight away, so just hit Run and you'll see the jump)

Comment: Added a fiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/gpv38jsv/

Comment: position is not an animatable property. Try to use `position:fixed` at start and then animate left and right property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, I dont have much time, but you can approach the issue by other perpective. Tell me how it was, here is an Idea that you can follow

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
 if(this.scrollY > 66){
   $('.course-list').addClass('side-bar');
    $('.course-list').css({top:this.scrollY})
  }else{
   $('.course-list').removeClass('side-bar');
    $('.course-list').css({top:0})
  }
})
```

```css
ul.course-list{
  position:relative;
  left:0;margin:0;padding:0;transition: all 1s linear;display:inline-block;right:auto;}

ul.course-list.side-bar{
  
  left:calc(100% - 200px);
}

body{
  height:1000000px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <ul class="course-list">
      <li>Testing only</li>
      <li>Testing only</li>
      <li>Testing only</li>
      <li>Testing only</li>
      <li>Testing only</li>
  </ul> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something more like this

```
@keyframes slideRight{
    from{left:0;}
    to{left:100%;}
}
```

Keep it simple and CSS will make it smooth.

Comment: It still jumps when changing from position:relative to position:fixed

Comment: I dont see the jump. Are you using the same fiddle from before?

Comment: Uh I had to make a change to get it to work, but it doesn't do anything in Internet Explorer (I have to make it work cross browsers, I know IE is sh*t).